# net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID Error while sending request from react app to Springboot backend with HTTPS Allowed

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, deployment, https

## **Background**

I have web application with frontend on **React js** and Backend in **springboot**. We had to deploy our application so that we can present it to the potential client. We deployed it on Amazon EC2 instance. The application is deployed using **github actions** and **Docker**. On the EC2 instance, a docker compose file is executed with pulls the images from **DockerHub**. Initially everything was working fine. React was able to send request to springboot and backend was also able to communicate back.

## **Problem**

Now we have bought a custom domain and we have bind the public IP of our instance with it. The domain is [ezgate.ai](https://ezgate.ai). I have setup nginx for reverse proxy on my ec2 terminal

**Nginx Config File on EC2 terminal**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ezgate.ai;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://18.205.106.161:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The public IP for Ec2 instance is **18.205.106.161** and the security group is following

[image: Securtiy Inbound rules]

When I hit ezgate.ai on web, the frontend is loaded

[image: FrontEnd Image]

But when I try to login by sending request, it gives me this error

[image: Error]

I have configured https in springboot application.

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:file.p12
    key-store-password: problem
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: stackoverflow
    key-password: problem
  port: 8443
```

I have my file of .p12 in resource folder.

When I hit the request from postman, the request works fine and I get response back too but from
react application I get the **net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID** error.

**React Config File for Axios**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const BASE_URL = "https://18.205.106.161:8443";

export const myAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});
```

I think the problem arises due to ssl certification but I don't know how to fix it.

**PS: I'm sorry if this is a repeated question. Please link the possible solutions. Thanks**